# Dropdown - value change on selection of 2 different dropdowns

Tags: javascript, html

I have 2 dropdowns. Each having 12 values in it.
I have associated it with other values.

So there are total 144 possibilities of choosing the things from dropdown. I want to display the total.

I have made the variable for displaying the total but its not working.

For example, in 1st dropdown I choose 9 and in 2nd I choose 10 then total should be shown = 500000

Remaining total should be displayed at initial stage.

Please help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're pretty new to this.  Good for you for getting this far.

Here's an updated codepen http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LcFjz

Here's what you did wrong:

1) When you called document.write, this happened before the other javascript was executed.  Therefore, `total` was undefined.  You can see this in the Chrome Dev Tools console.
2) Also, you had a problem with variable scope.  The variables `remaining` and `remaining1` do not exist outside their functions.  Therefore, the line

```
total = remaining.value+remaining1.value;
```

didn't do anything because neither of the two variables being added were defined.

Edit 1:
Since you want to display the remaining total when the page loads (without any kind selection), you need to change up a few things.
1) You need to call `updateTotal()` when the page is loaded.
2) You need to get the value of each select box without the 'change' event of those select boxes being fired.

I have updated the codepen to demo this.
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LcFjz

Comment: i saw other comments here full of code,but no message,i personally like this comment.

Comment: Ben, Thanks for telling where I went wrong.
You found correct that I am NEW to this. I make only designs/UI using HTML and CSS. This is the first time. 
I just forgot to mention one thing that remaining total should be displayed at initial point when page loads (without any kind selection). I hope it makes sense. If you could help.

Comment: NeoNirav, I have updated my answer accordingly.  Basically you just have to call the updateTotal() function and make sure to get the value of the select elements without a 'change' event being triggered.  See the updated codepen at http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LcFjz

Answer (score 0):

Try out this.

```
<html>

<body>
<select onchange="ChooseValue(this)">
        <option value="415760">0</option>
        <option value="415620">1</option>
        <option value="415350">2</option>
        <option value="414700">3</option>
        <option value="413400">4</option>
        <option value="410600">5</option>
        <option value="405000">6</option>
        <option value="390000">7</option>
        <option value="360000">8</option>
        <option value="300000">9</option>
        <option value="200000">10</option>
        <option value="0">11</option>
</select>
<select onchange="ChooseValue1(this);dispTotal();">
        <option value="415760">0</option>
        <option value="415620">1</option>
        <option value="415350">2</option>
        <option value="414700">3</option>
        <option value="413400">4</option>
        <option value="410600">5</option>
        <option value="405000">6</option>
        <option value="390000">7</option>
        <option value="360000">8</option>
        <option value="300000">9</option>
        <option value="200000">10</option>
        <option value="0">11</option>
</select>
<p>Total Remaining Amount is : <input id="oil"><input id="oil1"></p>
<script type="text/javascript">

  var total;
function ChooseValue(remaining) {
            document.getElementById("oil").value = remaining.value;
}
function ChooseValue1(remaining1) {
            document.getElementById("oil1").value = remaining1.value;
}
function dispTotal() {
total = parseInt(document.getElementById("oil").value) + parseInt(document.getElementById("oil1").value);
document.write("Total = "+total);
}

</script>

</body>
</html>
```